# “I’d like a refund ____ something”: Which preposition most normally connects "refund" to another noun?

Tags: prepositions

Which prepositions normally collocate with *“a refund*  ____  *something”* ? For example, if you were to return a product you purchased from somewhere, would you ask for:

1. a refund **on** the product
2. a refund **against** the product

Or would you use something else than either of those two?

Comment: 'A refund against ...' is far more formal, and usually used only for things like credit notes, supplier invoices, losses, a tax obligation....

Answer (score 3):

Apple Support think it should be 'for' :

> How to request a refund for an AppleCare plan

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202704)

And this is what appears to be the most common way of saying it according to the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refund+for%2C+refund+against%2C+refund+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crefund%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefund%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefund%20on%3B%2Cc0) (English) of 'refund for'/'refund against'/refund on'.

'Refund against' appears to be quite uncommonly used.

[Edit after Comment : The [BrE Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refund+for%2Crefund+against%2Crefund+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crefund%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefund%20on%3B%2Cc0) shows 50/50 'on/for' and zero 'against'

The [AmE Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refund+for%2Crefund+against%2Crefund+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crefund%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefund%20against%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crefund%20on%3B%2Cc0) is virtually identical to the English above.]

Comment: In Britain it would almost always be "refund for" - though "refund on" is possible, but perhaps suggesting only a partial refund.